# hreflang multi language with backend URL?

Tags: url, backend, language, hreflang

I am adding hreflang-tags to a multi-language Magento store.
I found the code below on here and used it in the page header.
It does what it's supposed to, but I'm looking for another solution.

```
<?php
$website = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getStores();
foreach ( $website as $store) {
$lang = $store->getConfig('general/locale/code');
    if (strtolower($lang) == 'en_us'){
        $lang = 'en-us'; // en-us or other
        }
    if (strtolower($lang) == 'nl_nl'){
        $lang = 'nl-nl'; // nl-nl or other
        }
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $store->getCurrentUrl() . '" hreflang="' . $lang . '"/>' . "\n";
}
?>
```

This returns a tag like:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/category?___store=english&amp;___from_store=english" hreflang="en-us"/>
```

But I would rather have a code that returns a tag with the actual URL as specified in the backend.

For example:

A product named "shoulder-bag" in category "bags"
returns an URL in English as: `example.com/bags/shoulder-bag`
And in Dutch as: `example.com/tassen/schouder-tas`

I'm also missing the code to specify a "default"

Can anybody help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a complete explanation on how to implement that feature : http://inchoo.net/magento/implement-rel-alternate-links-in-magento/

---

In your case your problem is your not telling Magento that the store is changing in your `foreach` loop.
You have to tell him with this function :

```
{foreach}  
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store->getId());  
[...]   
{endforeach}
```

Don't forget to reset to your current store after the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Followed the steps and it works for the product pages now. I've also implemented the "fix" suggested in the comments for non-product pages. It's still not the complete solution I'm looking for, but I'm a bit further than I was.

Comment: Can you update your question with my fix to see if there is no other error with that, and for other people reading the thread. Thank you.